# WordPress .htaccess and ErrorDocument 400

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am running into an issue where the permalink .htaccess code prevents custom error handling. When I delete the WordPress code, the error handling works properly.

Here is my code:

```
php_value memory_limit 96M
php_value upload_max_filesize 250M
php_value post_max_size 250M

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php

AddType application/msword doc
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel xls
AddType application/powerpoint ppt
AddType application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12 .docm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template dotx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12 potm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template potx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12 ppam
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12 ppsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow ppsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12 pptm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation pptx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12 xlam
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12 xlsb
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12 xlsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12 xltm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template xltx
```

Is there a way to keep the WordPress code intact and still have a custom error document for 400 errors?

Thanks in advance,

Scotty

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress works using a bootstrap index.php file.  All requests in the wordpress directory are handled by it. Therefore custom error documents will not work via apache, you need to create template pages for them in the Wordpress theme you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the link to a page I created which looks like this: 

ErrorDocument 400 /page-name/

This still produces the same result. Is there a different syntax I am missing?

Comment: This should explain what I was talking about.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom error page with your current theme in WordPress, you'll need to do the following...

1. Change your .htaccess ErrorDocument entry to `ErrorDocument 400  /index.php?error=400`
2. Create a `400.php` template page within your current WordPress theme. Be sure to include the normal `get_header()` and `get_footer()` code. Ideally, your theme already has a `404.php` files, so just duplicate this, rename it, then change the content/messages within.
3. Add the following code to your `functions.php`:

(you can put this in the last line or wherever)

```
/**
* 400 Error Code Reponse Header
* Note: This allows you to specify 400 RewriteRules in the .htaccess to use a custom 400.php WordPress template.
* Source: http://otroblogmas.com/retornar-410-wordpress/
*
* @param string $template
* @return string
*/
function e12_response_400( $template ) {
    if( '400' == $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] ) {
        status_header( 400 );
        if( file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/400.php' ) ) {
            return STYLESHEETPATH . '/400.php';
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'e12_response_400' );
```